# Convert a string representation of a set of tuples to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, eval

I have a long string representing a set of tuples:

```
my_string = '{(76034,0),(91316,0),(221981,768),(459889,0),(646088,0)}'
```

How can I convert it to the following dict?

```
expected_result = {76034: 0, 91316: 0, 221981: 768, 459889: 0, 646088: 0}
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Try using `ast.literal_eval`:

```
import ast
s = '{(76034,0),(91316,0),(221981,768),(459889,0),(646088,0)}'
print(dict(ast.literal_eval('[' + s.strip('{}') + ']')))
```

Output:

```
{76034: 0, 91316: 0, 221981: 768, 459889: 0, 646088: 0}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you do `literal_eval` on that string, it returns a set. But if you'd like a `dict`, you can convert it to one using `dict()`:

```
In [1]: from ast import literal_eval

In [2]: s = '{(76034,0),(91316,0),(221981,768),(459889,0),(646088,0)}'

In [3]: literal_eval(s)
Out[3]: {(76034, 0), (91316, 0), (221981, 768), (459889, 0), (646088, 0)}

In [4]: conv_s = literal_eval(s)

In [5]: dict(conv_s)
Out[5]: {459889: 0, 646088: 0, 221981: 768, 91316: 0, 76034: 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert string to its corresponding datatype in python using `eval`.

```
>>> a = '{(76034,0),(91316,0),(221981,768),(459889,0),(646088,0)}'
>>> eval(a)
set([(76034, 0), (459889, 0), (646088, 0), (221981, 768), (91316, 0)])
>>>
```

What you have posted is a set data structure.

Or since eval is indeed risky to use, you should use ast.literal_eval as in other answer. Also see this answer: [[Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval])

So that now the code becomes:

```
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval(a[1:-1])
((76034, 0), (91316, 0), (221981, 768), (459889, 0), (646088, 0))
>>>
```

Comment: `eval` is evil.